# How to skip step when the timeout is reached on wait function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

How can I prevent the script from stop beign executed when it hits the timeout limit?
My code looks like:

```
this.waitForSelector("#my_selector", function(){
     //...  magic code
} , null, 30000)
```

After reaching `30000` miliseconds it stops but there is more things to be scraped after this iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a **timeout** is to handle an non-nominal behavior *(cannot connect or else...)*.

Your function should stop. If in your case if it shouldn't, it means that your timeout is not set accordingly to your use case, you surely needs to increase it.

The [waitWhileSelector()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitwhileselector) function can take a callback in case of timeout, which would be your error handling.